Struck with Multiple Timeseries needed help
I am dealing with a sales data having multiple timeseries (hundred's), the requirement is to build a single model that can be used to forecast sales.
data format



Date
Company
Product
Region
Sales




2024-11-4
Apple
iPhone
Asia
1300



similarly we have other products of Apple in different regions
Note: different time series having different seasonality
I mapped Columns Company, Product and Region into a single column with number representing unique value for each series
like
[Apple, iPhone, Asia] = 1
[Apple, iPad, Asia] = 2
[Apple, Mac, Asia] = 3
[Apple, iPhone, Europe] = 4




Date
Series
Sales




2024-11-4
1
1300



sales is the target variable, extracted features like day, month, quarter, day_from_start (time_idx)
I have implemented Temporal Fusion Transformer
training= TimeSeriesDataSet(
    data=train_df, 
    time_idx='days_from_start',
    target='Sales',
    group_ids= ['Series'],
    min_encoder_length=max_encoder_length // 2,
    max_encoder_length=max_encoder_length,
    max_prediction_length=max_prediction_length,
    static_categoricals= ['Series'],
    time_varying_known_reals= ['day', 'day_of_week', 'month', 'days_from_start'],
    time_varying_unknown_reals=["Sales"],
    target_normalizer=GroupNormalizer(
        groups=["Series"], transformation="softplus"
    ),
)

validation = TimeSeriesDataSet.from_dataset(training, df, predict=True, stop_randomization=True)

batch_size = 32
train_dataloader = training.to_dataloader(train=True, batch_size=batch_size, num_workers=0)
val_dataloader = validation.to_dataloader(train=False, batch_size=batch_size, num_workers=0)

from pytorch_lightning.callbacks import EarlyStopping, LearningRateMonitor
from pytorch_lightning.loggers import TensorBoardLogger

early_stop_callback = EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss", min_delta=1e-4, patience=5, verbose=True, mode="min")
lr_logger = LearningRateMonitor()
logger = TensorBoardLogger("lightning_logs")

import lightning as pl
from lightning.pytorch.callbacks import EarlyStopping, LearningRateMonitor
from lightning.pytorch.loggers import TensorBoardLogger

from pytorch_forecasting import TemporalFusionTransformer, QuantileLoss

early_stop_callback = EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss", min_delta=1e-4, patience=5, verbose=True, mode="min")
lr_logger = LearningRateMonitor(logging_interval='epoch')
logger = TensorBoardLogger(save_dir="lightning_logs")

trainer = pl.Trainer(
    max_epochs=45,
    # accelerator='gpu', 
    devices=1,
    enable_model_summary=True,
    gradient_clip_val=0.1,
    callbacks=[lr_logger, early_stop_callback],
    logger=logger
)


tft= TemporalFusionTransformer.from_dataset(
    training,
    learning_rate= 0.03,
    hidden_size= 16,
    attention_head_size= 1,
    dropout= 0.1,
    hidden_continuous_size= 8,
    output_size= 1,
    loss= MeanSquaredError(),
    log_interval= 10
)

Where am I going wrong? Or can you suggest a better approach?
